# Update custom field values on edit address page woocommerce

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I have two custom fields included in the checkout page and also in the edit address page in myaccounts of woocommerce. The problem is the two custom fields 'billing_door' and 'billing_flatname' are not getting updated if changed from edit address page.
The code I'm using to display the fields is below. Now how do I update these fields and store it in the database. Thanks in advance

```
function custom_address_to_edit( $address ) {
global $wp_query;
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['edit-address'] ) && $wp_query->query_vars['edit-address'] != 'billing' ) {
            return $address;
}
if ( ! isset( $address['billing_door'] ) ) {
        $address['billing_door'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Door No / Flat No', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Enter your door number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-first','update_totals_on_change'),
        'value'       => get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_door', true )
    );
}
if ( ! isset( $address['billing_flatname'] ) ) {
    $address['billing_flatname'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Building Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Enter your building name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-last','update_totals_on_change'),
        'value'       => get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_flatname', true )
    );
}
return $address;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer your question but its too easy and simple:
Your code is always exiting from function at line 6 because the results of your `if` expression always returns true at line 5:

```
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['edit-address'] ) && $wp_query->query_vars['edit-address'] != 'billing' ) {
// above expression results would be: (either false or true) != (string) => this always return true
            return $address;
}
```